# Can't get the date on form-control using bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using [bootstrap-picker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in my porject. But, I am unable to get the selected date on form-control. How to get the date.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="date" data-provide="datepicker" formControlName="fromDate">
```

But, in fromDate field I am not getting selected date value.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Will you show your code for the component that this form html belongs to?

Comment: You should use any of [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples) or [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) to work in angular way.